# What is the difference between visual studio and visual c++ IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++

What is the difference between visual c++ and visual studio.
Also codes written in visual c++ do affect the portability and functionality of the code??

Comment: Did you even try to search for an answer before asking? However your mouse over the downvote button, and notice `effort`.

Comment: Not matter what thing you use to write code, you will end up compiling and testing your program till you know it is enough.

Comment: If you want portability use Java, functionality, Javascript, Python, modern frameworks for those two, and read documentations.

Comment: There used to be individual "language-centric" versions of Visual Studio, but this model is not used anymore. Just download VS 2017 Community Edition or buy VS 2017 Pro/Enterprise, and you can choose which languages you need with the [light-weight installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/22/the-lightweight-visual-studio-15-installer/).

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ is one of the languages that is supported in the Visual Studio IDE.  I'm not aware of a separate Visual C++ IDE, and relevant searches return information about working in Visual Studio.

These are all part of Microsoft's development platform, and as such they most easily target Windows platforms and .NET.  Beyond that I'm not sure I understand your question about portability.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing Visual C++ awhile back but Microsoft has moved to making Visual Studio their single IDE.

Check out this wiki link for more information. It says that Visual C++ has migrated into Visual Studio. However, it seems there might be some compatibility issues if you are using an older VS. I see you tagged VS2010 so you may want to read up on it depending on what functions you're using. Looks like VS2015 update 3 is the latest release that captures those functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B